# Generating a standalone apk from a bundle file (app.aab)

Tags: android, apk

I'm having problem creating a standalone apk from a bundle file in android using bundletool.

I wrote an application that contains multiple modules (downloadable separately using splitInstallManager) and deploy it as a bundle (app.aab) file.
So far so good, however for whatever reason, I also need to generate a standalone apk for one specific device and I cant seem to get it done.

What I have:
1. my app.aab
2. my keystore
3. specs file for the device generated using `"bundletool get-device-spec"`

What I am doing:

```
java -jar bundletool.jar build-apks --ks=[my keystore] --ks-pass=[password] --ks-key-alias=[alias] --key-pass=[key password] --bundle=app.aab --output=app.apks --device-spec=device-specs.json --overwrite
```

According to

```
bundletool help build-apks
```

when you pass device specs parameter to the tool it by default use "--mode=default" which means that the generated apks file should contain: "... If not set or set to 'default' we generate split, standalone and instant APKs. ...".

Problem is that generated app.apks file contains only "splits" subfolder.

In addition I get the following warning:
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil (file:/home/oberon/Downloads/bundletool.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

How do I generate a standalone apk ?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standalone APKs are only generated if `minSdkVersion < 21`.

If you want a universal APK, you can use `--mode=universal` which will build a single APK that contains everything. As documented below https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool

Comment: where is it documented ? (the "minSdkVersion < 21")

Comment: The general Android App Bundle documentation explains that split APKs are only used from Android L (SDK 21), and that standalone APKs are generated otherwise.

Comment: Pierre here is the documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool

Comment: "A fundamental component of serving optimized applications is the split APK mechanism available on Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher." https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/app-bundle-format